# Jetty maven plugin does not load Service Loaders in application class path

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

Jetty and jetty-maven-plugin: 9.4.19.v20190610

I am using a HashLoginService and I want the username and password to be encrypted with "scrypt" algo. The box standard Jetty only provides plain, crypt and md5 encryption as seen in [HashLoginService](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-security/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/security/HashLoginService.java) and most importantly [Credential](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/security/Credential.java#L66)

This [enhancement](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=485625) was added in Jetty 9.4 where by the `Credential` class would consult the standard JVM `ServiceLoader` mechanism to load additional `CredentialProvider` class.

In my project I have a dependency like this which contains the credential provider implementation. It also has the correct manifest entry with the interface/implementation

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
   <artifactId>myartifact-contains-credential-provider</artifactId>
   <version>0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I can verify this by simply doing `ServiceLoader.load(CredentialProvider.class)` **in my test class** which has the dependency in the classpath to make sure that my provider is present.

When I run this via the jetty-maven-plugin this provider is NOT available. I confirmed this by adding a breakpoint in the Credential class in jetty-util library. What am I doing wrong?

My guess is that when running via the jetty plugin the jetty loads these extensions using the system/server classpath and my dependencies/libraries are only present in the application classpath. Can someone tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: What you are doing seems sane, and should work.  Consider filing this as a problem on the Eclipse Jetty project issue tracker - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thank you! I filed https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3922

Comment: I made an experiment where I copied my jar with the provider into a directory and started jetty using `java -jar jetty-runner.jar --lib dir-with-provider` and I can see now it is detected properly. So basically it works when I place the provider in the Server's container classpath but will be more useful if it can also scan the application classpath?